# Get special sequence of integer numbers

Tags: javascript, random

**Task:** Get array of random integer (less than 10) numbers and random sequence of mathematical operations (multiplication and addition) which, when applied, will give a even number

**Example:** `genOddSeq(4) -> [[6, 6, 6, 9], ['+', '*', '*']] (6 + 6 * 6 * 9 = 330)`

**Code:**

```
function genOddSeq(count) {
  let getRandomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.ceil(max) - Math.ceil(min))) + Math.ceil(min)
  let result = []
  let operations = []
  let numbersComp = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result.push(getRandomInt(1, 10))
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
    operations.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '*')
  }

  numbersComp += operations[0] == '+' ? result[0] + result[1] : result[0] * result[1]

  for (let i = 1; i < count - 1; i++) {
    numbersComp = operations[i] == '+' ? numbersComp + result[i + 1] : numbersComp * result[i + 1]
  }

  if (numbersComp % 2 != 0) {
    result[getRandomInt(0, count)] += 1
  } 

  return [result, operations]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function name is strange. You wanted to get a sequence of random numbers and operations whose result is an *even* number. But you named your function `genOddSeq`. Also, avoid abbreviations. Write code for the human, not the machine.

Instead of using an empty array and a loop to fill that array, consider using `Array()`, `Array.fill()` and `array.map()`. For example, creating an array of 10 random values from `0` to `1` would look like:

```
const tenRandomDecimals = Array(10).fill().map(Math.random)
```

You can do the same for the operations.

Now instead of hard-coding the logic of the operation selection inside a ternary, consider using a key-value pair where the key is `+` and `*` and the values are functions that accept two numbers which do the actual operation. When you generate an array of random `+` and `*`, just use them to get the actual function in the key-value pair.

```
if (numbersComp % 2 != 0) {
  result[getRandomInt(0, count)] += 1
}
```

This bit of logic is strange. Do you *really* need to get a random value? Or can you just use one from a known location, like the first number?

Last but not least, tests. It's always good practice to start with tests. Even other code review posts include a minimal form of test to verify the code is working.

Anyways, here's how I'd implement it. A bit longer, but there's no surprises. There's no state held, no variables to keep track of. Also using `const` both as a signal and a guarantee that the value will not change during runtime.

```js
const operationFunctions = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
}
const operationKeys = Object.keys(operationFunctions)
const getRandomInteger = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.ceil(max) - Math.ceil(min))) + Math.ceil(min)
const getRandomOperationKey = () => operationKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * operationKeys.length)]
const range = size => Array(size).fill().map((v, i) => i)

const getEvenResultSequence = count => {
  const firstNumber = getRandomInteger(1, 10)
  const numbers = range(count - 1).map(() => getRandomInteger(1, 10))
  const operations = range(count - 1).map(getRandomOperationKey)
  const result = operations.reduce((c, v, i) => operationFunctions[v](c, numbers[i]), firstNumber)
  const adjustedFirstNumber = result % 2 ? firstNumber + 1 : firstNumber

  return [[adjustedFirstNumber, ...numbers], operations]
}

console.log(getEvenResultSequence(4))
console.log(getEvenResultSequence(4))
console.log(getEvenResultSequence(4))
console.log(getEvenResultSequence(4))
console.log(getEvenResultSequence(4))
```